# Nested ul li with a php array and a specific count

Tags: php, arrays

I have 10 users in an array:

```
$array = array(
    "aaa",
    "bbb",
    "ccc",
    "ddd",
    "eee",
    "fff",
    "ggg",
    "hhh",
    "iii",
    "jjj",
);
```

And I want to display lists based on 5 or fewer users e.g.:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>aaa</li>
            <li>bbb</li>
            <li>ccc</li>
            <li>ddd</li>
            <li>eee</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>fff</li>
            <li>ggg</li>
            <li>hhh</li>
            <li>iii</li>
            <li>jjj</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

At the moment I have:

```
<ul>
<?php foreach($users as $user): ?>
    <li><?php echo $user ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

However I am not creating the inner uls. What is the best way to approach this? Using a for loop and counting out 5? Or is there a neater method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to split an array into multiple arrays with a specified number of items.

```
<ul>
<?php
$users = array_chunk($array, 5);
foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo "<li><ul>";
    foreach ($user as $idv) {
        echo "<li>" . $idv . "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul></li>";
}
?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look an alternative solution :)

```
<li>
 <ul>
     <?php
        echo '<li>'.join('</li><li>',array_slice($array,0,5)).'</li>';
    ?>
 </ul>
</li>

<li>
 <ul>
   <?php
       echo '<li>'.join('</li><li>',array_slice($array,5,10)).'</li>';
  ?>
</ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
<?php 
$lenght = count($users);
for( $i=0; $i<$lenght; $i++ ){
if( $i%5 == 0 ){ 
   echo '<li><ul>';
}
echo '<li>'.$users[0].'</li>';
if( $i%5 == 4 || ($i+1==$lenght) ){ 
    echo '</ul></li>';
}
}?>
</ul>
```